# Trouble adding Internet permission in Android Studio

Tags: android

When I added the following line to **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
< uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It shows two errors:

1. Error:The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
2. Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Name\AndroidStudioProjects\Sunshine\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

However, without That line of code, it compiles successfully and runs on my phone.

Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/rnbsi0Yi

I have double checked the package name and everything else seems fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: remove the space at the start and end of tag

Comment: change the package to your application package not the package where your activity resides

Comment: @Raghunandan : The space doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JomyEmmanuel that's for the 1st point

Comment: @PramodYadav: My application package resides in com.example.name.sunshine.app , I guess .If I make any changes to it, other identifiers and tokens get unidentified. Moreover, as I said before the  gradle compiles successfully if I don't request for Internet permision.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thank You. Thanks a lot. :) Little did I know that spaces between tags would create compilation errors. My bad!!